# Excel 2016: Populate column with list based on matching criteria from another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I tried to phrase the title as best I could and I'm going to do my best to explain. I'll take any suggestions on re-naming the title, if needed.

I have two sheets that I'm trying to use for tracking rounds played by players in a sport. They're essentially the same data, just presented differently.

In one sheet, I have 12 rows, each row representing a player, with the player's name in Column B.

For each row, there are 11 columns, each representing each round of a game.

e.g.,

```
================================================
|  A  |    B    |    C    |   ...   |    M     |
================================================
| No. | Player  | Round 1 |   ...   | Round 11 |
------------------------------------------------
|  1  | Male 1  |    I    |         |    I     |
|  2  | Male 2  |    I    |         |    I     |
|  3  | Male 3  |    I    |    I    |          |
|  4  | Male 4  |    I    |    I    |          |
|  5  | Male 5  |    I    |    I    |    I     |
|  6  | Male 6  |         |    I    |    I     |
|  7  | Male 7  |         |    I    |    I     |
|  8  | Female1 |    I    |         |          |
|  9  | Female2 |    I    |    I    |          |
|  10 | Female3 |    I    |    I    |    I     | 
|  11 | Female4 |         |    I    |    I     |  
|  12 | Female5 |         |         |    I     |
```

Only 5 *male* players can play in a round. 
Only 3 *female* players can play in a round.

So if the player is in, I enter an "I" in the column for the applicable round, and empty if they are not playing that round.

In the other sheet, I have rows that represent the players that are "IN" and the players that are "OUT".  I then have columns that represent the round of the game.

In these cells, however, I'm currently manually entering (copy/paste) the names of the players who are in and/or out for that round.

```
================================================
|  A  |    B    |    C    |   ...   |    M     |
================================================
| No. | Status  | Round 1 | Round 2 | Round 3 |
|-----------------------------------------------
| 1   |   IN    | Male 1  | Male 3  | Male 1  |
| 2   |   IN    | Male 2  | Male 4  | Male 2  |
| 3   |   IN    | Male 3  | Male 5  | Male 6  |
| 4   |   IN    | Male 4  | Male 6  | Male 7  |
| 5   |   IN    | Male 5  | Male 7  | Male 7  |
| 6   |   IN    | Female1 | Female2 | Female3 |
| 7   |   IN    | Female2 | Female3 | Female4 |
| 8   |   IN    | Female3 | Female4 | Female5 |
| 9   |   OUT   | Male 6  | Male 1  | Male 3  |
| 10  |   OUT   | Male 7  | Male 2  | Male 4  |
| 11  |   OUT   | Female4 | Female1 | Female1 |
| 12  |   OUT   | Female5 | Female5 | Female2 |
```

How can I populate the players' names auto-magically for the columns in the second sheet based on the row and status from the first sheet?

**EDIT:**

Updated my question to provide more precise details on the data I'm using.

**EDIT:**

Added column names to the examples.

Comment: This will require a macro, but it shouldn't be a particularly complicated one. However, we're not much of a script-writing service. Have you tried anything particular yet? If you have, please let us know what you're tried and we'll see what we can do to help bridge the gap between "try" and "succeed".

Comment: I edited my question to provide some more detailed information about my sheet(s) setup so that your promising answers can better apply.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with two “helper matrices”. 
A “helper cell” is a cell that derives/computes some intermediate value
from the input data. 
This intermediate value is then used in another cell(s)
to produce the desired result. 
It’s common to have a “helper column” in a sheet of tabular data. 
I look forward to seeing whether somebody
can streamline my answer and make it more elegant,
but this is the best I was able to come up with in 59 minutes.

It’s possible to put helpers on the same sheet as the actual data,
in different column(s) or row(s), typically hidden. 
Or you can put them on separate sheets. 
Since this answer calls for two of them, I’ll illustrate both techniques;
you can then choose to use one technique consistently.

I’ll assume that your source data (presented in your question)
are in `Sheet1!A2:D8`, with the headers in Row 1. 
Put

```
=IF(B2="", "blank", B2)
```

into cell `AB2`, and drag/fill down to `AB8` and to the right to Column `AD`. 
This results in

```
   |    AA    |    AB    |    AC    |    AD    |
---+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 1 |          |          |          |          |
 2 |          |   I      |   blank  |   I      |
 3 |          |   I      |   blank  |   I      |
 4 |          |   I      |   I      |   blank  |
 5 |          |   I      |   I      |   blank  |
 6 |          |   I      |   I      |   I      |
 7 |          |   blank  |   I      |   I      |
 8 |          |   blank  |   I      |   I      |
```

I trust no explanation is necessary.

Now it gets more complicated. 
Create `Sheet3` and enter the following formulas:

- `B2` → `=MATCH("I", Sheet1!AB$2:AB$8, 0)`
- `B3` → `=MATCH("I", OFFSET(Sheet1!AB$2,B2,0):Sheet1!AB$8, 0) + B2`
- `B7` → `=MATCH("blank", Sheet1!AB$2:AB$8, 0)`
- `B8` → `=MATCH("blank", OFFSET(Sheet1!AB$2,B7,0):Sheet1!AB$8, 0) + B7`

Drag/fill cell `B3` down to `B6`.
If you ever change your scheme so you have more than two “out” players
at a time, you will need to drag/fill cell `B8` down appropriately. 
And, as before, drag/fill Column `B` to the right to Column `D`. 
You should get:

```
   |    A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |
---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
 1 |         |         |         |         |
 2 |         |      1  |      3  |      1  |
 3 |         |      2  |      4  |      2  |
 4 |         |      3  |      5  |      5  |
 5 |         |      4  |      6  |      6  |
 6 |         |      5  |      7  |      7  |
 7 |         |      6  |      1  |      3  |
 8 |         |      7  |      2  |      4  |
```

Explanation:

- `B2` contains the (relative) location of the first `I`
  in the range `Sheet1!AB$2:AB$8`. 
  This is `1`, because `Sheet1!AB2` contains `I`,
  and it is the first cell in that range. 
  Similarly, `C2` and `D2` contain `3` and `1`, respectively,
  because `Sheet1!AC4` and `Sheet1!AD2` (the third and first cells,
  corresponding to Player3 and Player1, respectively),
  are the locations of the first `I` in those columns.
- Looking at `B3` — `OFFSET(Sheet1!AB$2,B2,0)` is `OFFSET(Sheet1!AB$2,1,0)`,
  which is equivalent to `Sheet1!AB3`. 
  So this `MATCH` is looking at the range `Sheet1!AB3:AB8`. 
  This `MATCH` will also return `1`,
  because `Sheet1!AB3` contains `I`, and it is the first cell in *that* range. 
  Then we add `B2` (`1`) to that, getting `2`,
  which is the location of the *second* `I` in `Sheet1!AB2:AB8`.
- Similarly, the `MATCH` in cell `D4`
  is looking at the range `Sheet1!AD4:AB8`. 
  This `MATCH` will return `3`,
  because `Sheet1!AD6` is the first cell in *that* range that contains `I`. 
  Adding `D3` (`2`) gives us `5`, because that row corresponds to Player5.
- Then we do the same thing in Rows 7 and 8, only looking for `blank`.

  I wouldn’t have needed the `Sheet1!AA:AD` helper matrix,
  except, apparently, you can’t use `MATCH("", …)` to find a blank cell.

Now we can just coast downhill
and put `=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$8, Sheet3!B2)` into `Sheet2!B2`.

```
+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Status | Round 1 | Round 2 | Round 3 |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| IN     | Player1 | Player3 | Player1 |
| IN     | Player2 | Player4 | Player2 |
| IN     | Player3 | Player5 | Player5 |
| IN     | Player4 | Player6 | Player6 |
| IN     | Player5 | Player7 | Player7 |
| OUT    | Player6 | Player1 | Player3 |
| OUT    | Player7 | Player2 | Player4 |
```

[image: screenshot corresponding to the above]

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know. Thank you!!

Comment: Hi @Scott, I gave this a try, but as with the other answer, I could not get this to work as expected, but close. Instead of the player names, I get the same "I" or "O" status. I've tried tweaking the necessary columns, etc., but again, probably related to the fact that there's more to my sheet that the watered down example provided.

Answer (score 0):

This VBA code will do the trick

```
Public Sub players_rounds()
    first_sheet = "Sheet1"
    second_sheet = "Sheet2"
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wk1 As Worksheet
    Dim wk2 As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wk1 = wkb.Worksheets(first_sheet)
    Set wk2 = wkb.Worksheets(second_sheet)
    wk1_lastColumn = wk1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    wk1_lastRow = wk1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    count_in = 0
    For i = 2 To wk1_lastRow
        If wk1.Cells(i, 2) = "I" Then count_in = count_in + 1
    Next i
    wk2.Cells.Clear
    wk2.Rows(1).value = wk1.Rows(1).value
    wk2.Cells(1, 1).value = "Status"
    count_out = wk1_lastRow - count_in - 1

    For i = 2 To count_in + count_out + 1
        If i <= count_in + 1 Then
            wk2.Cells(i, 1).value = "IN"
        Else
            wk2.Cells(i, 1).value = "OUT"
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 2 To wk1_lastRow
        thisplayer = wk1.Cells(i, 1)
        For j = 2 To wk1_lastColumn
            playervalue = wk1.Cells(i, j)
            playerround = wk1.Cells(1, j)
            If playervalue = "I" Then
                firstrow = 2
                lastrow = count_in + 1
            Else
                firstrow = count_in + 2
                lastrow = count_in + count_out + 1
            End If
            For k = 2 To wk1_lastColumn
                If wk2.Cells(1, k) = playerround Then
                    For m = firstrow To lastrow
                        If wk2.Cells(m, k) = "" Then
                            wk2.Cells(m, k) = thisplayer
                            m = lastrow
                            k = wk1_lastColumn
                        End If
                    Next m
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Open VBA / Macros with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F11</kbd>, click on `ThisWorkbook` right-click and *insert* a module under it. Paste the code on the right side.

Check that the values of the variables `first_sheet` and `second_sheet` match with the names of your worksheets.

Whenever you execute this macro it will update the second sheet according to the values on first sheet.

To make it even more *automagical* double in Macros, double click the first sheet, in the right side select *Worksheet* and *Change*.

Make it look like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call players_rounds
End Sub
```

Now, every time you change something in the first sheet, the second one updates.

Comment: Hi @jcbermu, so I gave this a try but it doesn't work as expected. I'm sure this probably because there's a lot more to my sheet than the watered down example I provided. I haven't been able to figure out the variables to update to properly test, given my lack of VBA knowlege.